Access Parameter Description in DigSilent Powerfactory via Python
I have the following problem:
I´m trying to access the "params" section of a Powerfactory path. I can access the parameters itself, which are given back as list [0, 0.02, 0.04, 0.03,.....] and so on. The problem is, I also need to find the description of the "params", which is shown in Powerfactory, but I can´t access them via Python.
The parameters are stored in Powerfactory as follows:
enter image description here
I want to loop through all the parameters and get their corresponding description or name, to further work with them.
Also interesting is, i can access each variable by calling it directly, for example
oSignal.T6 == 0.02, or oSignal.TRe == 0.01.
Any help on how to access the name of the parameter itself is welcome. Thanks in advance!
def get_signal_measurements_data(app):
    """
    Retrieves Signal Measurements data from the PowerFactory application.

    Args:
        app: The initialized PowerFactory application object.

    Returns:
        dict: A dictionary containing descriptions and their corresponding values.
    """
    try:
        oGen = app.GetCalcRelevantObjects('*.ElmSym')[0]
        oPlant = oGen.c_pmod
        sModels = oPlant.GetContents('*.ElmComp*', 1)

        # Get signal measurements data
        unitrol_index = find_index("UNITROL 1000", sModels)
        if unitrol_index == -1:
            raise ValueError("UNITROL 1000 not found")
        oUnitrol = sModels[unitrol_index]
        sModels = oUnitrol.GetContents('*.ElmDsl', 1)

        sm_index = find_index("01_Signal Measurements", sModels)
        if sm_index == -1:
            raise ValueError("01_Signal Measurements not found")
        oSignalM = sModels[sm_index]
        print(oSignalM.GetAttribute("params")) #(This is only for trying to see the attributes)

        # Extract data of signal measurements
        signal_measurements = {
            "Description": [
                "U_SPh_meas", "TRv_3p", "TRv_1p", "TRi", "TRe", "T6", 
                "PLL_select", "IeN_to_IeAGL"
            ],
            "Values": [
                oSignalM.U_SPh_meas, oSignalM.TRv_3p, oSignalM.TRv_1p, 
                oSignalM.TRi, oSignalM.TRe, oSignalM.T6, 
                oSignalM.PLL_select, oSignalM.IeN_to_IeAGL
            ]
        }
        
        return signal_measurements

    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error retrieving Signal Measurements data: {e}")
        sys.exit(1)
        

This is my code so far. I want to automate the Extraction of data by looping through each parameter, extracting the name of the parameter and then saving it.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

So i just found the solution for my own problem:
you can access the parameters by accessing "typ_id" attribute first and then collecting the stored "sParams" attributes.
